# An exercise of autonomous ODE and phase flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am recently studying ODE and stuck by the following exercise:

Let
$$\dot{z}=f(z)\ ,\ 0\le t\le T \ ,\ z(0)=z_0$$
be an autonomous ODE, where $f$ is a locally Lipschitz function.

Define $\varphi_T:\ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $,   $\varphi(z_0)=z(T)$. Then do we have $$\det(J_{\varphi_T}(x))>0\ ,\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$where $J$ denotes the Jacobi matrix?

I have been thinking for it for a very long time with no effective ideas, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define
$$
w(t)=\det(J_{\phi_t}(z_0)),
$$
then by the rules of determinant derivatives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}J_{\phi_t}(z_0)
=\frac{\partial f(\phi_t(z_0))}{\partial z_0} 
=J_f(\phi_t(z_0))·J_{\phi_t}(z_0)\\
\implies
w'(t)=\text {Tr}(f'(\phi_t(z_0)))w(t)
$$
so that $w$ never changes its sign, and $w(0)=1$.